# Structs in C confusion

Tags: c, struct, typedef

I have a c file that starts with a struct I am calling stringtable, looks like this

```
struct stringtable {
   int table[];
   int numElements = 15;
};
```

And I have a header for it that has this typedef

```
typedef stringtable *stringtable_ref;
```

When I compile with gcc I get the errors:
expected identifier or '(' before '[' token
expected ':' before 'int'

like I have declared the struct wrong. I have done structs in C like this before so my question is: Am I making a mistake declaring my struct? Does it need to have a tag before the semicolon? Are there only certain places I am allowed to declare a struct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
struct stringtable {
   int table[];
   int numElements = 15;
};
```

A flexible array member like `int table[];` can only be the *last* member of a `struct` (with at least one more member).

And you can't assign a default value to a member in a `struct` declaration, C doesn't support that.

Comment: What is? That you can't give a default value? I don't know why it's not allowed, but I see no reason why it should be, and it would make `struct_with_default_value *ptr = malloc(100 * sizeof *ptr);` pretty awkward, one might expect the default values set there, but `malloc` certainly won't do it.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have a `static` member in your struct, you cannot initialize the members upon declaration.

You need to create an instance of your struct before initalizing the members:

```
 struct stringtable str_table;
 str_table.numElements = 15; 
 //etc
```

Answer (score 0):

I would also expect that you need in the header `typedef struct stringtable *stringtable_ref`